# How to find list of columns which are "Read-only" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find all columns of a table which have "read-only" access for some analysis.

how do can this be done in SQL Server?

I tried following but its not giving me desired results:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) as ObjectName, Name as ComputedColumn
FROM syscolumns
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY( id ,name, 'SystemDataAccess') = 0
AND name like 'my_table_name'
```

Comment: There's no such thing a read-only column in Sql Server. Write access is GRANTed per user account, and the `sa` user will always have write access. So are you asking about the current user, some specific users, or all users (excluding sa)?

Comment: Ya all users excluding "sa" will be fine though

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Read-Only" in the all users perspective (as in under normal circumstances nobody should be able to write to the column regardless of user specific access) the below type of thing could be used to return the columns that are identity or computed values (I can't think of any other specific cases where you cannot write to a column)...

```
DECLARE @Tbl nvarchar(500)='MyTableName';
SELECT T.Name, C.*
FROM sys.tables AS T
    JOIN sys.Columns AS C ON T.Object_id=C.object_id
WHERE T.Name=@Tbl
    AND (
        C.Is_Identity=1
        OR C.Is_Computed=1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution without the JOIN:

```sql
SELECT name FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'MyTableName' 
    AND (is_identity = 1 OR is_computed = 1);
```